# JS Date YYYY-MM-DD Returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, date, iso

I have HTML `Date` inputs that return a string in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'

I then want to put this into the `Date` Constructor so that I can get it converted into ISOFormat (for use of Mongo Querying)

However, the results are unexpected.
Doing `new Date('2020-06-25')` returns "Wed Jun 24 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)". Note that this is the day prior. Why does this happen and how can I change this to get the current date? THanks

Comment: 'YYYY-MM-DD' **is** ISO 8601 format. If you want fully qualified, then append "T00:00:00Z".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new `Date` object in JavaScript, it expects the argument to be in GMT. It then converts it to your local timezone `GMT-0400`, which explains why its 4 hours off. You can set the timezone by appending it to the date string: `new Date('2020-06-25 GMT-0400')` should give you "Thu Jun 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400".

Comment: "*... it expects the argument to be in GMT*" is incorrect. Dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd are parsed as UTC, but other date formats are not. "2020-06-25 GMT-0400" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. `new Date('2020-06-25 GMT-0400')` produces an invalid date in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: @RobG what do you suggest then?

Comment: @Liky—if you want it parsed as local, then add "T00:00:00" so that the entire string is, for example, "2020-06-25T00:00:00". It was a terrible [*decision of the TC39 committee*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87) to parse YYY-MM-DD as UTC, but it's been that way for far too long to change it now.